# ACF next/previous on single post template from relationship field

Tags: wordpress, navigation, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

I have ACF with a relationship field to choose posts from a custom post type (artworks). Instances of the relationship field occur on multiple pages but with different post entries chosen. 
It works fine to display the chosen posts as a list but when I get down to the single-artworks template level how can I get the prev and next links to adhere to only the chosen posts in the parent relationship field?

```
next_post_link() 
previous_post_link()
```

on the single template seems to traverse all entries in the post type, ignoring the choices and order of the relationship field.

Seems like a need to provide the single template with an array of postIDs from the relationship field to choose from, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your custom pagination to show next and prev links as below:

```
$args = 'get you relationship query';
$curr_id = $post->ID;
unset($args['paged']);
$args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
$tempposts = query_posts($args);
$post_ids = array();
if($tempposts):
    foreach($tempposts as $post){
        $post_ids[] =  $post->ID;
    }
endif;
$current_index = array_search($curr_id, $post_ids);
// Find the index of the next/prev items
$prev = $current_index - 1;
$next = $current_index + 1;

//Prev post 
get_permalink($post_ids[$prev]);

//Next post
get_permalink($post_ids[$next]);
```